# Paths and Acceleration Proofs

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help with 2 proofs, which I can intuitively grasp but I am not sure how to construct proofs of.

Show that, at a local maximim or mininum of $|| \mathbf r (t)||$, the vector $ \mathbf r' (t)$ is perpendicular to $ \mathbf r (t)$.

and

Let $\mathbf c$ be a path in $\Bbb R^3$ with zero acceleration. Prove that $\mathbf c $ is a straight line or a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A local maximum or minimum of $||r(t)||$ occurs when its derivative is zero, i.e. $<r(t),r(t)>'=0$, where $<,>$ denotes to inner product . By product rule, you have $2<r(t),r'(t)>=0$ which means $r(t)$ is perpendicular to $r'(t)$

For the second question, assume $r'(t)=c$ is a constant vector (I hope it is what you mean by zero acceleration). You can easily solve the differential equation to get $r(t)=ct+u_{0}$ where $u_{0}$ is a constant vector.